# Doing one sql query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

There are three tables

posts table

```
id          username
1           ahmed
```

users table

```
id          title
1           test post
```

post_users

```
user_id     post_id
1           1
```

post_users (have two fields user_id and post_id) many to many

when I want to send post id=1, I want to select users from users table that don't have a row in post_users table (in one query). How?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something along these lines. INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USERS.ID
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN POST_USERS
ON USERS.ID=POST_USERS.ID
WHERE POST_USERS.POST_ID <> your_input_value
```

I made a few assumptions, if this doesn't work please provide some more details.